# Search contact by posible name or number like default caller app

Tags: android, search, contacts

I write an dialer app and want do search according to letters on num pad in contact name or number;
for example:

keyboard like below:

1  .........**2** abc.....**3** def

**4** ghi... **5** jkl.......**6** mno

**7** pqrs **8** tuv.......**9** wxyz

and when user type 666 suggest Mom for example or 328 for Father and so on.

there is any way to search like this with Contact Provider?

my current solution:
generate a key for all name (ex: for mom = 666)
and save this key and other info in my db (or an array) and use this key for search:

key LIKE %input% OR number LIKE %input% and ...

But I Want do this without create new db and just use android contact provider.

Thanks.